# Why did the crew members not feel anything during creating the paranormal documentary series?

Tags: plot-explanation, american-horror-story

While watching the sixth episode of *American Horror Story* I was wondering how it was possible that none of the crew members felt anything in the house when they were creating the paranormal documentary series titled "My Roanoke Nightmare".

At once when everyone was brought into the house in the sixth episode "**Return to Roanoke: Three Days in Hell**", everything unusual started happening.

Comment: I wonder if this just gathers "primarily opinion-based" votes because people think it's about a real crew of an actual documentary, rather than the fictional documentary crew inside of the actual story it seems to be about.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson It was like this in my case. I've retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In episode 6 its explained that nothing happened to the film crew during the original production because they weren't filming during the Blood Moon, which is the time of year that the Butcher comes out to kill.

This explanation is brought up when one of the actors asks why nothing happened when they were filming.  The estranged husband asks what time of year was it.  I believe the camera even cuts to the moon to indicate that the Blood Moon is coming.  The idea for filming during the Blood Moon for the reunion was to get some scares.